# How does redirecting from a post method to get method work?

Tags: express, npm, handlebars.js

The server doesn't recognize any get request except for the post method after executing some queries in the mongodb.

The express middleware takes the post method and after interacting with the database and using the res.redirect() to get to other get methods, the server doesn't recognize the request at all. I tried using res.all(). This showed that the request was seen but no action was taken.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Product = require('../models/product');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {`//homepage
    res.render("index");
}

router.post('/add',function(req,res next){  
    //Product model
    var prod = new Product({
        //data here
    });

    prod.save(function(err,res2){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect('/error');
        }
        else{
            mongoose.disconnect();
            console.log("Complete1");
            return res.redirect('/');
            console.log ("Complete2);
        }
    }); 
}
```

After I get to the post method it should redirect to the homepage

Answer (score 0):

The problem may not be with the backend, but with the frontend. If you are using AJAX to send your POST request, it is specifically designed to not change your url.

Use window.location.href after AJAX's request has completed (in the .done()) to update the URL with the desired path, or use JQuery: $('body').replaceWith(data) when you receive the HTML back from the reques

Comment: I am redirecting from the post method as I wrote the sample code above. The form tag of the HTML redirects to the post method of the router and after interacting with the database tries to redirect it back to get method from within the the post method and that's where the problem arises of not being able to use the get methods.

Comment: Are you using JQuery or AJAX?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it in the post. I'm using express middleware.

Comment: Try this: Replace var router = express.Router(); with var app = express(); and subsequently change router.get and similar routes to app.get and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks I fixed it. I was disconnecting the mongoose after each interaction that cause other get methods (which used mongoose) connection unresponsive. Thanks